# Update NSArray stored in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsuserdefaults

Is it possible to update my array named `customerName` which is stored in NSUserDefaults?

This is my code so far:

```
accounts = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSArray *customerName = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"J BLOGGS", @"J BLOGGS", nil];
[accounts setObject:customerName forKey:@"customerName"];
[accounts synchronize];

NSLog(@"%@", [[accounts objectForKey:@"customerName"] objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, you have to retrieve your immutable array and make a mutable copy, then write it back to user defaults.

```
NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *customerNames = [userDefaults objectForKey:@"customerName"];
NSMutableArray *mCustomerNames = [customerNames mutableCopy];
mCustomerNames[0] = @"Some Other Name";
[userDefaults setObject:mCustomerNames forKey:@"customerName"];
[userDefaults synchronize];
```

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this when I reload my app, it reloads my old values :S

Comment: Are you sure you're calling synchronize after setting new values?

Comment: Yes I am indeed/. Could it be I have my default declared as a property? @property (nonatomic, retain) NSUserDefaults *accounts;

Comment: Look into the way you persist the customer names for the first time when your app launches. Perhaps you're recreating the array with old values every time the app is launched and save it into the user defaults.

Comment: Yes, it works, but is totally sucks. If you have a reasonably deep hierarchy within your userDefaults .plist - then you must read and replace whole hierarchies at the top-level, every time you want to change a value at the lowest-level nodes. Not only is it inefficient, one cannot "KVO" (observe) changes on the lower-level entries. Only the top level items. I wonder why Apple didn't invest just a little more in KVO/KVC compliance of their UserDefaults. (supporting set/get Value:forKeyPath:)